# I'd like to be able to migrate my own questions

Tags: feature-request, superuser, migration, serverfault

I recently had a question migrated from [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/77028/perforce-proxy-server-caching-selective-files-closed) to [SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/89505/perforce-proxy-server-caching-selective-files) that generated the kind of answers I was looking for. In the past I had posted [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/58131/perforce-re-reverse-integrating-a-changelist) to SU that generated a Tumbleweed badge for me, and now I'm wondering if I'd get the answers I'm looking for if I had posted it to SF instead. Technically I'm pretty sure the ability to migrate my own questions from SU to SF is doable- would this make sense as a feature? Perhaps it should only be available once a user has earned a certain amount of rep on the source site? Or perhaps it should cost some amount of rep to perform this migration? Either path could serve to minimize abuses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag the post for moderator attention using the "in need of moderator intervention" reason, and indicate which site you'd like your question migrated to. If the question is of decent quality and is on-topic for the target site, moderators can migrate it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Flag them for moderator attention.

In my opinion, a lot of the hardcore, very detailed source control questions belong on SO. I don't know who, other than developers, would know the nitty-gritty details of source control.

Comment: I did end up copy/pasting the original perforce question on SO; I was hoping for a more elegant way of accomplishing this in the future, so this works; thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to review questions carefully before migrating, and it both these cases I **believed** they were better answered by a more professional audience, either SF or SO. The problem with this however is unless I do the research for a product I don't know, it may get migrated the wrong direction.

The keywords that triggered the first migration was **proxy**, **server** and **work** followed by the rest, which in my mind immediately triggered the needs of SF. I do however agree with Jeff regarding the second question possibly being better on SO.

**Please do not crosspost**.
These post end up being moved and closed as multiple duplicates and cause unnecessary negative voting. It's a new emerging pattern.

- Flag the question for moderator attention if you don't have enough rep to vote.
- Vote to close for the site you want it moved to if you have enough reputation, we do track these votes and check the questions.

> **Disclaimer**
>   Moderators are human, we make mistake, and bad judgement calls. We are not however always right. In fact, depending on who you ask, we are rarely right.

Comment: how about a capability to cross-post?