# Migrating question to different .SE for lack of answers

Tags: discussion, migration

I have used several .SE's which were very helpful. However to stay on topic for some questions I went to other .SE's which did not have the same number of active members due to which questions stay unanswered very long. If a question is suitable for several .SE's and at the most appropriate one it stays unanswered because of low population on that .SE, is that a good reason to migrate it to another (although less) suitable .SE?

Basically a .SE does not work as well as another if theres less people on it. Even though its more on topic on the less functioning .SE, its much more helpful to post it on the good functioning .SE. So you could say the less functioning .SE should not have been created, on the other hand you could say that all active people more engaged with subtopics on the busy .SE that better fit on the less functioning .SE should really spend more time there.

Comment: If the .SE's are very similar, this might actually work out well.

Comment: Essentially, no. Questions that are on topic for a site should not be migrated elsewhere. And it is counter-productive to the growth of a site to ignore it and ask questions that would be on topic for it elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm not sure what my stance on this is.

Comment: @CodyGray I did not find that question, I found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31408/id-like-to-be-able-to-migrate-my-own-questions/31438#31438 , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87741/what-should-be-done-when-a-question-that-is-asked-on-two-se-sites-is-found/87838#87838 , and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113427/to-migrate-or-not-to-migrate . 
It is almost a duplicate. You might argue that my question is a broader one: its not just about SO and beta sites.

Comment: @StephenTG Say I post a question on physics (20K users) or DSP (4K users) but dont get attention or an answer and the question is also on-topic for mathematics (60K users) or SO (2000k users). Is that a good reason to migrate it to mathematics or SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level of "functioning" is not relevant here; the only thing that matters is where it is on-topic. As an extreme example to illustrate the point; you wouldn't post a question about [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), just because it's more active.

That said, there can sometimes be some minor overlap. Still, the above applies; the question you post on each site must be on-topic for that site. I can certainly imagine a problem that could involve questions on multiple sites - but it's only legitimate to post in such a way if each question on each site is on topic there.

Comment: As a Jewish programmer, is it OK to drink wine [in order to increase my productivity](http://xkcd.com/323/)?

Comment: @CodyGray If, by "OK", you mean, "Absolutely Required", the answer is Yes. Although this has nothing to do with being Jewish. ;)

Comment: @Andrew Barber Well I think alot of DSP problems can be stated in such a way that it is on topic in the physics .SE and almost any problem in physics can be stated in a general manner to be suitable for the mathematics .SE. So "there can sometimes be some minor overlap" would be as much and understatement as saying "OK" when you mean "absolutely required".

Comment: @Leo It has to do with how exactly you are approaching the problem and, as you state above, how it is *stated*. If you are stating a question differently, tailored to the topic of the site in question, then it's not *really* the same question. Basically, we don't disagree there at all. :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Well if mathematics users would indeed consider a physics problem to not be mathematical then how you originally stated it could indeed be a reason not to migrate. Then still you could have answered the *spirit* of my question: how you state it does not matter for moving your problem to another SE,if you delete and restate at other .SE.Then again most physics questions would fit just nicely on th mathematics .SE so statement is probably not an issue in the first place.Not that I am trying to disagree with you or anything ;) http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/37433372.jpg

Comment: @Leo hehe... love the meme! Can't argue with what you said, lest you enjoy it too much!