# Accidentally posted on wrong forum

Tags: support, migration

Any chance you can transfer my posts from stack overflow meta on to this meta list.  100% my bad in my head stack exchange and stack overflow are synonymous and i have to correct my thinking.

I don't mind all those minus scores stay on my SO post, but please don't hit my reputation here also. It's either one or the tothet

Comment: Posts on child meta sites (such as Meta Stack Overflow) do not impact the rep on the main site.  Your post is best left where it is.

Comment: I was going to close this as a dup of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31408/id-like-to-be-able-to-migrate-my-own-questions) but it is more wise to follow @psubsee2003's advice.

Comment: Small quibble, Stack Exchange sites are not forums

Comment: @Santiago beat me to it because I wanted to post this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum

Answer (score 13):

There are three things you can do - in order of preference:

1. Leave things as they are. It's OK to post things that concern the network on a child meta. The community managers and devs monitor all the meta sites between them, so your post will get spotted.
2. Delete and repost here. Obviously this will only work if there are no answers or only one zero scoring answer.
3. Flag your post for moderator attention, explaining why you want it migrating. There would have to be a compelling reason for us to honour that request.

However, bear in mind that down-votes here *will* cost you lost reputation, unlike down-votes on a child meta which are free of any reputation cost.

Comment: Uh, is the priority between 2 and 3 actually right? Isn't it always encouraged to properly flag for migration instead of just reposting? The asker's wishes for migration should always be honored anyway (if the question is on-topic on the target site, of course).

Comment: @ChristianRau moderator bandwidth is limited.  Anything a user can handle themselves is preferable.  Plus, a flag to migrate on busy sites could take days.  A delete and repost can be done in minutes.

Comment: @ChristianRau The point is that 2. doesn't require the intervention of a moderator and if there are no answers it's safe to delete and repost.